# check if instance present in list

Tags: python, list

Is there a built-in function to determine if instance of a class exists in a list?
Currently I am doing it through a comprehension

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...     
>>> l1=[5,4,3,A(),8]
>>> e=[e for e in l1 if isinstance(e,A)]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [`any(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)
>
> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.

```
>>> class A(object): # subclass object for newstyle class (use them everywhere)
        pass

>>> l1=[5,4,3,A(),8]
>>> any(isinstance(x, A) for x in l1)
True
```

By using a [generator expresson](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

```
(isinstance(x, A) for x in l1)
```

in conjuction with `any`, `any` can short circuit and return `True` upon finding the first `True` value (unlike the list comprehension).

Comment: You might want to mention the benefit of using a generator here is that `any` will short-circuit and return `True` as soon as it finds a `True` value.

Comment: I suggest you add link to `any` documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: Cool, Python suggest use the built-in functions if possible